# Is Vista Home Basic eligible for Seven upgrade pack?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I have genuine windows vista home basic which came with my Dell Inspiron 15 laptop. Is vista home basic eligible for upgrade pack? I mean can I purchase Seven Premium upgrade pack instead of buying the whole package?

One more question is, I have removed vista from my laptop & running Seven RC version. Should I need to have Vista running to install the upgrade pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Adding a bit of general licensing knowledge to benefit the site)

There is a lot of confusion in this, I recently asked my rep at Microsoft and was told along the following...

Windows Vista with free upgrades - Purchase Windows Vista now and get a free upgrade to 7 later... Available to all versions excluding home basic (as this is being phased out for mainstream markets).

There are two sorts of upgrades available -

1. Anytime Upgrade which if you own Vista Home Basic, you can go up to Ultimate... If you own 7 Home Premium, you can go up to Ultimate e.t.c. The other sort of upgrade is what you are talking about -
2. Windows 7 Upgrade editions on the hand, you simply purchase the edition you want and as long as you have a previous licence, you have the "right" to install it. Feel free to buy *any* Windows 7 upgrade package, and as long as you have Vista, you can use it.

As for actual feasibility, Windows Vista and 7 for upgrade actually require the OS to be installed. There are a few workarounds such as installing without a serial key so it thinks you have a fully packaged product and then installing over the top as a upgrade, however as much as many people have had success, I would not recommend it, unless you are sure you know you want to do it.

I am still not in favour of upgrading in place, I am always for new installations, but I know on Vista and 7, it is **a lot** better, and many people have had success, so Install Vista, then install your 7.

Personally, I would never upgrade from a Beta, RC, or aything other than RTM (Final Edtion).

To sum up - 1, Yes, you can buy a upgrade and use it... 2, Yes, install Vista (preferred) or use the method above.

Comment: I know I have talked about the upgrade over method above, however I do not believe it is illegal as it is only bypassing the fact that Microsoft no longer allow you to just put in a disk to verify that you own it. At the end of the day, he is not trying to get anything for free and Microsoft end up with the exact same about of $$ in their bank.

Answer (score 1):

To install the upgrade pack, you'll need to reinstall Vista as no upgrade is possible from any Beta or RC of Windows 7.

Concerning the upgrade pack, it's should be available for any version of Windows Vista.